# Assigning value calculated through pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a function that calculates an integral like this:

```
/* Complete this function to perform the trapezoidal rule using pthreads. */
void *compute_using_pthreads(void *inputs)
{
          double integral;
          int k;
          threadParams *args = (threadParams *) inputs;

          float a = args->a;
          float b = args->b;
          int n = args->n;
          float h = args->h;

          integral = (f(a) + f(b))/2.0;

          for (k = 1; k <= n-1; k++) {
                 integral += f(a+k*h);
          }     

          integral = integral*h;

          printf("Solution computed using pthreads = %f \n", integral);
}
```

It's called within `main` like this:

```
int i;
          for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADs; i++) {
            trapThread = (threadParams *) malloc(sizeof(threadParams));
            trapThread->a = a;
            trapThread->b = b;
            trapThread->n = n;
            trapThread->h = (b - a) / (float) n;

            if (pthread_create(&slaveThread[i], NULL, *compute_using_pthreads, (void *) trapThread) != 0) {
                printf("Looks like something went wrong..\n");
                return -1;
            }
          }
```

My problem is, since I am running 4 threads, the results string `Solution computed using pthreads =` is printed four times.

My question is, how do I, within main, call `compute_using_pthreads` and save its return data into a `double` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another variable `res` to the struct `threadParams` and store the result in it.

```
      integral = integral*h;
      args->res = integral;
```

Now, from `main()`, you'll be able to read this `integral` calculated by each thread.

Currently, you have no identifier to the access `malloc`'ed memory since you are using the same variable `trapThread`. Instead, use an array or `malloc`'ed list of pointers so that you'll be able to access it later.

Obviously your main thread will have to wait for the other threads to complete i.e. if it exits then the whole process will die.